# Link Inside Select Box

Tags: html

Is it possible to display an html link inside a multi select box that can be navigated to?

Comment: "No", but you can workaround the limitation. (sup jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

You cannot make a link inside a `select` element, however you *can* make a select element that will change the page when an option is selected. (Probably not what you want)

Additionally, you can make your own pseudo-select box using a combination of `input:radio` elements, CSS, and JavaScript. This pseudo-select box can be customized to contain anchor elements and other such things if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the value attribute to store the url

```
<select >

    <option value="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
    ...

</select>
```

have use javascript to retrieve the value when an item is selected and redirect to that URL.

Comment: like so
`$("select.quickNav").change(function(){
     if ($(this).val()!='') {
          window.location.href=$(this).val();
     }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an onClick event into the option button that will behave like an anchor tag.

```
<select multiple>
    <option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.google.com'" >google</option>
    <option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'">stackoverflow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This only works on <select multiple>. We need a single drop-down.