# cakephp sort by name and price in dropdown

Tags: html, cakephp, hyperlink, html-select

i want to sort the products according to their name and price.  When i do `<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name'); ?>` it works. But it is not working in dropdown list. Thanks for any suggestion. My Code is

```
<select name="">
<option>Position</option>
<option> S<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name'); </option>
<option><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('price'); ?></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you understand what you're trying to do? You're putting an `<a>` link produced from `Paginator::sort` inside an `<option>` element belonging to a `<select>`. This isn't possible in HTML and hasn't got anything to do with cake.

You can read more and/or try the solutions described here:

- [Link Inside Select Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382730/link-inside-select-box)
- [using href links inside <option> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)